# Label not applied in job after adding another service discovery

Tags: prometheus

I used to have a prometheus config to scrape nodes for node-exporter using a simple file which was working fine

```yaml
- job_name: 'node-exporter'                                 
  honor_labels: true                                        
  file_sd_configs:                                          
    - files:                                                
      - "./node-exporter.yml"
```

node-exporter.yml

```yaml
- targets:
  - node1:9100
  labels:
    instance: node1
```

so value for label `instance` was properly set to `node1`

I then added in the same job, the service discovery `openstack_sd_configs` and a couple of entries in `relabel_configs` to clean the labels and ignore IPv6 entries.

```yaml
openstack_sd_configs:
  - role: instance
    port: 9200
    ...
relabel_configs:
 - source_labels: [__meta_openstack_private_ip]
   # drop ipv6 resources
   regex: '^(([0-9a-fA.......'
   action: drop
   # set proper instance
 - source_labels: [__meta_openstack_instance_name]
   target_label: instance
```

After that the label `instance` of entries from `file_sd_configs` had value `node1:9100` in the "target labels" seen in the UI of prometheus, as if the label was now ignored.

I added some additional entries to relabel_configs that were supposed to work according https://relabeler.promlabs.com/, for example:

```yaml
- source_labels: [__meta_openstack_instance_name, instance]
  target_label: instance
- source_labels: [instance]
  regex: '(.*):.*'        
  action: replace         
  target_label: instance
- source_labels: [instance]
  regex: '.*;(.*)'        
  action: replace         
  target_label: instance
```

but `labels` from `file_sd_configs` got ignored.

Eventually I created two separate jobs to workaround this, but I'd like some explanations how I should have done.